# How can my subclass properly inherit a static variable

Tags: java, inheritance, static, superclass

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public int x, y;
    public static int z;
}
```

I want every subclass of SuperClass to have the static variable z. Naturally z will contain a different value for each subclass. I'm hoping to avoid defining z in every subclass, since it's going to be a functional dependancy of values x and y; Is this possible?

Comment: No, `static` variables belong to the class that declares them. The best you can do is hide them.

Comment: "*Naturally z will contain a different value for each subclass*" => no it won't...

Comment: @assylias Sorry. Naturally it should..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike instance variables that are "one per instance", `static` variables are not "one per subclass" - they are "one per declaring class". In other words, subclasses of `SuperClass` share `SuperClass.z`, but they cannot "override" it on a class-by-class basis.

It does not mean that you cannot implement it yourself: on way to make your own per-subclass storage of integers is adding a `static Map<Class,int> zs` to `SuperClass`, with optional functions for accessing the data:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public int x, y;
    private static Map<Class,Integer> zs = new HashMap<Class,Integer>();
    protected static int getZ(Class c) {
        Integer res = zs.get(c);
        return res == null ? -1 : res.intValue();
    }
    protected static void setZ(Class c, int v) {
        zs.put(c, v);
    }
}
class SubClassOne extends SuperClass {
    public int getZ() {
        return SuperClass.getZ(SubClassOne.class);
    }
}
class SubClassTwo extends SuperClass {
    public int getZ() {
        return SuperClass.getZ(SubClassTwo.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or I could just put `public static int z = x` in each subclass. It doesn't result in any more lines of code than your suggestion regardless of how many subclasses I may want, right?

Comment: @user2651804 This is correct. The only difference is that the superclass would not have an easy access to a per-subclass repository of `z`s.

Comment: In my case I don't need this. I always planned on accessing the z values from outside classes by referring SubclassA.z, SubclassB.z etc.  I probably have some horrible design flaws :P

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way to do this is to have a `z()` method or similar in the abstract class, and override the method in the subclasses you want.

Example:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
  public int x, y;

  protected int z() {
     return 42; // protected so only subclasses can see it - change if required
  }
}


public class SubClassOne extends SuperClass {

  public void foo() {
    // do something...
    int z = z();
    // something else...
  }
}

public class SubClassTwo extends SuperClass {

  @Override
  protected int z() {
    return 1;
  }

  // use z() accordingly
}
```

Comment: I think this is the thing the asker wants. I'd add public static fields to the classes, so that I don't *need* to have an instance to retrieve the field. An example of this in real world use is Antlr: `Lexer` has `public abstract String[] getTokenNames();`, subclasses have `public static final String[] tokenNames = {...};` and implement the method.

Comment: @SillyFreak Well, what his SubClassTwo does is what I wanted to achieve - just in a smarter way, which isn't possible it seems. It doesn't beat `public static z = 1` either, so why do unneccesary code?

Comment: there is a very important difference between these two regarding dynamic binding. Consider two instances `SuperClass sup; SubClass sub;`, and a nonstatic method `SuperClass.foo()` which accesses `z`. Both `SuperClass` and `SubClass` declare `static int z;`. `sup.foo();` and `sub.foo();` will both use `SuperClass.z`, because of static binding. The behavior you probably expected is that the `z` accessed depends on the identity of the object, not the class where `foo()` is declared. If that's what you wanted, then you're fine, but document that decision *very* well; it might confuse other devs.

Comment: Silly Freak - that's a good point. I'm not a fan of static on a general level because of testing reasons, but in this case it could be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly then do

```
public abstract class SuperClass {

  public int x, y, z;
  public SuperClass(int z) {

    this.z = z;

  }

}
```

then any class that extends this class inherits z;

Comment: maybe even a getter and setter for z.